# Fabric-karaf, Apache Camel, fabric-camel: "Component is not started"

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, fabric8

I have a problem with fabric-camel component.

It detects my camel endpoints from blueprint:

```
2014-10-02 15:27:43,598 | INFO  | 26c-351-thread-2 | FabricPublisherEndpoint          | 204 - io.fabric8.fabric-camel - 1.1.0.CR5 | Child: jetty:https://127.0.0.1:1221/https/incontrol?matchOnUriPrefix=true
2014-10-02 15:27:43,598 | INFO  | 26c-351-thread-2 | FabricPublisherEndpoint          | 204 - io.fabric8.fabric-camel - 1.1.0.CR5 | Consumer: jetty:https://127.0.0.1:1221/https/incontrol?matchOnUriPrefix=true
```

But then I get "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component is not started"

```
2014-10-02 15:27:43,602 | ERROR | 26c-351-thread-2 | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 197 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.0 | Unable to start blueprint container for bundle pl.com.xxxxxx.esb.esb-incontrol-proxy
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to initialize bean .camelBlueprint.factory.inControlProxyContext
...    
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: fabric://incontrol:jetty:https://127.0.0.1:1221/https/incontrol?matchOnUriPrefix=true due to: Component is not started
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component is not started
    at io.fabric8.camel.ZKComponentSupport.createGroup(ZKComponentSupport.java:53)
```

More detailed stacktrace http://pastebin.com/BFrPBarp

My blueprint.xml (relevant parts):

```
<!-- Boundary beans -->
<bean id="httpsRouteBuilder" class="pl.com.xxxxxxx.camel.builder.HttpsRouteBuilder">
    ...

    <property name="incomingUri" value="fabric:incontrol:jetty:${endpoint.https.incoming.url}?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
    <property name="outgoingUri" value="${endpoint.https.outgoing.url}?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>

    ...
</bean>
...
<camelContext id="inControlProxyContext" trace="false" streamCache="true"
              xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint-2.10.0.xsd">
    ...
    <routeBuilder ref="httpsRouteBuilder"/>
    ...
</camelContext>
```

My pom.xml (relevant parts):

```
<!-- Fabric -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>fabric-camel</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I'll try to enable debug logging and see what else I can find. Unfortunately I still don't understand the underlying issue: why the component was not started?

Version info:

- Karaf: 2.3.0.redhat-610379
- Fabric: 1.1.0.CR5

Answer (score 0):

You can try to enforce the component to be manually instantiated and started before the route is started: Try something like this:

```
<endpoint xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" id="fakeFabricEndpoint" uri="fabric:fake:jetty:${endpoint.https.incoming.url}?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
```